# Count elements having a specified attribute

Tags: jquery

I need to count all elements having the attribute "ind", regardless of what the value of that attribute is.

```
<select name="region_id" class="selSumo selRelated" ind="1">
```

e.g. I guess and adaptation of

```
var cnt = jQuery(['ind']).length;
```

I have three different selects on the page, each with attribute "ind", but I get cnt = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("[ind]").length will give the count of all the elements with attribute ind

codepen URL for reference - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RRPmZv

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
              alert($("[ind]").length);
          });


            <select name="region_id1" class="selSumo selRelated" ind="1">
              <select name="region_id" class="selSumo selRelated" >

                <div ind="1">1</div>
```

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was wrong because I have 3 select elements on the page having attribute "ind" but it only alerts "1".

Comment: it works fine for the select irrespective of the select number with attribute ind.Please verify the same codepen URL again and let me know if it works

Comment: Yes, I see that it does work. Must be something sumoSelect js is doing to my selects, although I see all the "ind" attributes in firebug, so....weird.